# Is there a way to make a file appear at the top of Phabricator diffusion?

Tags: configuration, phabricator

I have a README file that I would like to appear at the top of diffusion, so that I do not have to scroll or find in page. Is there some configuration option to do this automatically or set file display order manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's only in alphabetical order.  You can rename the file to `.README` or `_README` to bump it to the top of the list.